# win32com.client.GetActiveObject does not find App when run as an SVN post-commit hook

Tags: python, svn, pywin32, enterprise-architect

I created a python script (packaged as post-commit.exe) to run as an SVN post commit hook. Yes, the hook runs, but this is the line I am having problems with:

```
App = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("EA.App")
```

This issue does not happen on Windows 7, but is now happening on Windows Server 2012 R2 with the same installs:

TortoiseSVN-1.9.0.26652-x64-svn-1.9.0.msi

pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.3.exe

python-3.3.0.amd64.msi

I used pip to explicitly install pypiwin32, but I can't tell if it actually worked or not (or if it matters). It says it's installed, but at the end of the install it gives me the following even tho I ran as admin:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\python33\\Lib\\site-packages\\pythoncom.py'
```

When I open this .exe it runs fine and works as expected, but when it is kicked off by the actual SVN commit, SVNTortoise gives me the error message below. I had problems with SVN deleting PATH for other lines of code, so I have also tried the full path to where EA.exe lives. I ran wmic get ProcessID and also tried what that gave me... but these do not work either:

```
App = win32com.client.GetActiveObject(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA\EA.App")
App = win32com.client.GetActiveObject(r"C:\PROGRA~2\SPARXS~1\EA\EA.App")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spent a lot of time googling and searching stackoverflow for answers, but can't find anything for this specific problem. Thanks!!

SVN Error output:

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code -1) with output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ATC_Generator.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 78, in GetActiveObject
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ATC_Generator.py", line 61, in <module>
  File "site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
  File "site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
  File "site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
Failed to execute script ATC_Generator
```

Comment: When I read "server" I immediately think about EA running as service which does not work. You need a logged on user.

Comment: Thomas, I am logged into Windows Server 2012 and running the enterprise architect program, with EA.exe showing up as a process. I'm running it exactly the same as I would on my Win7 machine. The post-commit.exe even works when I open it, but it does not work when SVN runs it. I tried looking at what is in the path env variable (which SVN may be deleting when it runs the hook), but those paths also did not work when hardcoded into GetActiveObject().

Comment: I'm no Windoze expert. But if you say SVN is running it, you likely start some kind of process which will (also likely) run as some system user and not the EA user which has the rights to run EA.

Comment: So EA is already running and I'm just trying to get a handle to that. I ran across some info about find the process in the Running Object Table, but have been unable to figure anything out there. I don't know what SVN is doing differently that prevents it from finding this running process.

Comment: Maybe you reduce it to the basic permission problem and find a answer/question for that first. The EA/python audience is not that large, but the basic pythonist group will be.

Comment: The problem is likely that, as Thomas described EA has been started by a different user then the (system) user executing the svn post-commit. In that case the system user probably doesn't have access to the ea.exe process started by another user.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, it only happens on Windows Server 2012, but not on Windows 7. I tried giving full access rights to the System and that didn't help either. Thanks for the help trying to figure it out, but I'm stuck